# Breadth First Search returning a null exception pointer even though returned ArrayList is not empty

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, breadth-first-search

In the test case for the grader, the case is stating for the call of `getMinLadder("aa", "aa")` it is receiving a `NullPointerException`. Whenver I run the client with that method call I receive the correct answer. I am stumped on how a call to that method would some how result in a null pointer exception.

Below is my *Breadth First Search* code. I know it's probably a mess but it does work for all other cases. Do you see anything in this snippet that may be the reason I am failing that test?

My `isWord()` method and `getHammingDistance()` method are not included. They work correctly. `isWord()` just scans a hashset of words to see if it contains the string I'm looking for. `getHammingDistance()` is pretty simple as well.

```
  public List<String> getMinLadder(String start, String end) {

  start.toLowerCase();
  end.toLowerCase();
  neighbors.clear();

  minLadder = new ArrayList<String>();

  HashSet<String> visited = new HashSet<String>();

  Queue<Node<String>> queue = new ArrayDeque<Node<String>>();

  Node<String> root = new Node<String>(start);
  queue.add(root);

  Node<String> currentNode;

  if (start.equals(end)) {
     minLadder.add(start);
     return minLadder;
  }

  if (getHammingDistance(start, end) == -1) {
     return minLadder;
  }

  if (isWord(start) && isWord(end)) {

  while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
     currentNode = queue.remove();
     neighbors.addAll(this.getNeighbors(currentNode.getValue()));
     queue.removeAll(visited);

     for (String obj : neighbors) {
        if (!obj.equals(end)) {
           visited.add(obj);
           Node<String> node = new Node<String>(obj);
           queue.add(node);
           node.next = currentNode;
        }
        else {
           Node<String> lastNode = new Node<String>(obj);
           queue.add(lastNode);
           lastNode.next = currentNode;
           queue.remove();

           Node<String> pointer = new Node<String>(null);
           pointer.next = lastNode;

           while (pointer.next != null) {
              minLadder.add((String) pointer.next.getValue());
              pointer.next = pointer.next.next;
           }
           java.util.Collections.reverse(minLadder); 
           return minLadder;    
        }
     }
  }
 }
  return minLadder;
  }
```

Comment: If you are getting a `NullPointerException`, please post the stack trace for that exception. Also, if you are asking peopleto help you debug your code, then posting a [mcve] may help.

Comment: I can't post the stack trace, the nullpointer exception is through a separate grading program. All I get is the sentence null.pointer.exception. I don't receive the error when running the method with the same parameters myself so I can't identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Analysis of your code reveals that when the two parameters are equal, flow ends:

```
public List<String> getMinLadder(String start, String end) {

// some code

if (start.equals(end)) {
    minLadder.add(start);
    return minLadder;
}
```

So the NPE must be in the “some code” part, which is:

```
start.toLowerCase();
end.toLowerCase();
neighbors.clear();

minLadder = new ArrayList<String>();

HashSet<String> visited = new HashSet<String>();

Queue<Node<String>> queue = new ArrayDeque<Node<String>>();

Node<String> root = new Node<String>(start);
queue.add(root);
```

The *only* line that *can* cause a NPE is:

```
neighbors.clear();
```

and then only if **`neighbors` is `null`**.

Comment: I think that was an error and was able to correct it so thank you very much for that, but now I am getting a different null pointer exception when the method call is getMinLadder("cat", "dog") I must have some other variable in there pointing too null but I can't find it